# Databaselink to a Oracle User

Tags: database, oracle

I have an oracle schema call REPORTS that contains tables and data. I also created an Oracle user call YOUR_REPORTS that have read access to all the tables and data in schema REPORTS. So another system can use select * from YOUR_REPORTS.table1; table1 is actually a table in schema REPORTS.

My question is: can you create a database link on another system that connect to user YOUR_REPORTS, instead of connecting directly to REPORTS schema? Or a databaselink has to be connecting to a physical schema, not a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, but you need to have synonym to hide the original schema.

Simple Demonstration

```
SQL> create user report identified by report;

User created.

SQL> grant resource, connect to report;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create user your_report identified by report;

User created.

SQL>  grant resource, connect to your_report;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> alter  user report quota unlimited on users;

User altered.

SQL> alter user your_report quota unlimited on users;

User altered.

SQL> conn report@salespdb
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> create table test(id number);

Table created.

SQL> grant select on test to your_report;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn sys@salespdb as sysdba
Enter password: 
Connected.

SQL> grant create synonym to your_report;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn your_report@salespdb
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> create synonym test for report.test;
Synonym created.

SQL> conn jay@salespdb
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> create database link dbl_report connect to your_report identified by report using 'salespdb';

Database link created.

SQL> select * from test@dbl_report;

no rows selected
```

Comment: if I don't create the synonym call test. How do I select from a table? SELECT * FROM your_report.test_table@dbl_report?

Comment: No, it should be `report .table@dblink`. Because the `your_report` is not the owner,  it only has select privilege.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a user is a schema and vice versa.  So, yes, when you create a db link into the Oracle Db from another DB, Oracle or otherwise, you would provide the connection information for the user/schema you want to connect to.  This is accomplished, at least in Oracle, via `CONNECT TO` and `IDENTIFIED BY`.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK <link name>
 CONNECT TO <user> IDENTIFIED BY <pwd>
 USING <connection info>;
```